# include "/directory/filename.php" not found. include "directory/filename.php" found. why?

Tags: php, include

`include "/directory/filename.php"` writes out error 
`include "directory/filename.php"` finds it.

I want to upgrade our server hardware, and I installed apache/php/pgsql to the new server.

On the old hardware, the first include code runs perfectly, so I guess something is wrong in my php.ini file.

I've tried to change the `include_path` in my `php.ini`, it had no effect

> Warning: include_once(/class/class_masterplan.php)
>   [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in D:\PHP\work.php on line 218
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '/class/class_masterplan.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\php')
>   in D:\PHP\work.php on line 218
>
> Fatal error: Class 'masterplan' not found in D:\PHP\work.php on line
>   219

I would like to know, what server config variable could cause/solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you use a leading slash, the application will think it is an absolute path, which it isn't. If you omit that slash, you are working with a relative path. See also: http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm

Comment: If I use absolute path, shouldn't it search from the DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: I don't know exactly anymore, but I thought it depends on your system configuration. I think what you want is to start from your domain/site root. There are more articles about that. Good luck!